# how to delete 3 lines including Bookmarked lines after each bookmarked line in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I have a very long text document, and I bookmarked a lot of lines, but is there any way to delete couple of lines after bookmarked lines including bookmarked lines .

All bookmarked lines has a same text, that how bookmarked them.
Thanks in advance

Here is a sample file

```
Line 1 
Line 2
Line 3
Common Line
line 5
Line 6
Common Line
line 8
Line 9
line 10
```

there is no pattern into any of these lines except on line 4 and line 7 have identical text.

What I want to do is to delete Line 4(Common Line), Line 5 , Line 6 and Line 7(Common Line).

Comment: I dont know why I am getting negative for this question. what is the problem about it?

Comment: This sounds like something that would be easy to do with regular expressions. Can you explain what criteria you used for bookmarking lines, and exactly what you want to delete? Giving examples is very helpful too.

Comment: @Marathon55 above is what i want to do

Comment: So do you also want to delete Line 8 and Line 9 since those are the next two lines after a Common Line?

Comment: @Marathon55 not Line 8 and Line 9 .
put it this way, anything between first two Common Line to be deleted.  and if there is another two Common Line, do the same

Answer (score 1):

Use Notepad++ regex Find-and-Replace:

Find what:

```
Common Line[\s\S]+?Common Line
```

Replace it with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^Common Line$).*?\1\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Match case* or uncheck depending on your requirement
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(               : start group 1
  ^Common Line$ : literally
)               : end group 1
.*?             : 0 or more any character, not greedy
\1              : backreference to group 1 (ie. same content)
\R?             : any kind of linebreak, optional in order to deal with last line if it hasn't linebreak
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Line 1 
Line 2
Line 3
line 8
Line 9
line 10
```